# Gsm Sim800l Module

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm

I am using below code for send sms but SMS Sent sucessfully but save in SIM memory & not able to see message text :

```
serialSIM800.write(“AT+CMGF=1\r”); //sending SMS in text mode
delay(1000);
serialSIM800.write(“AT+CMGS=“9827927887”\r”);
delay(1000);
serialSIM800.write(“Emergency at IIST\r”); // message
delay(1000);
serialSIM800.write(0x1A);
delay(1000);
Serial.println(“SMS sent successfully”);
```

Please help.[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set SMS Text Mode Parameters `AT+CSMP` to `AT+CSMP=17,167,0,0`

This setting  is resolve your issue.

Comment: Could you edit your answer and add an explanation as to why this solution works?

Answer (score 1):

After few minutes of using Google, I found [a library](https://github.com/cristiansteib/Sim800l) that contains everything you need to send/receive SMS and phone call. Here's the code I made in two minutes.

Currently I don't have SIM800L module, so I can't test it. Be sure you type a valid number format. For Croatia it's +385 XX XXX XXXX. +385 is an "international dialling code" for Croatia. Don't forget to put + before IDC.

```c++
serialSIM800.write("AT+CMGF=1\r"); 
serialSIM800.write("AT+CMGS=\"");
serialSIM800.write("PHONE_NUMBER");           
serialSIM800.write("\"\r");       
serialSIM800.write("Emergency at IIST");
serialSIM800.write("\r0x1A");
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but my actual problem is i am from india and in my sim800l module the same network operator different sim card some are able to send proper message and i am able to receive it but some of them are not able to send the message and are sending the blank message to sim memory.